# How can I prepare to rent an electric car in France?

Tags: france, car-rentals, electric-vehicle

Planning to rent a car for an upcoming trip to the Normandy countryside, driving from Charles de Gaulle airport, and I've come across a number of electric rentals. I have an EV in the US and the idea of renting one for our trip sounds ideal, and have already figured out what I need to do to rent/drive in France. But I'd appreciate tips on how to find charging stations, any networks I should register with, and anything else I should know about driving & renting an EV in France?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So as always when travelling with EVs, I would say planning is key for a successful - and less stressful - journey. There are quite a lot of charging stations throughout the whole country: According to Europcar, there are more than 30,000 charging points in France.

The following websites look promising:

- [chargemap.com](https://chargemap.com/)
- [ev-charging.com](https://ev-charging.com/at/en/catalog/index/fr/Haute-Normandie)
- [chargehub.com](https://chargehub.com/en/charging-stations-map.html)
- [izivia.com](https://www.izivia.com/en/interactive-map-2)

Another tip is to check the parking lots of Auchan supermarkets, as some of them have charging stations for electronic vehicles. And often, you can use them for free.

As you said that you already have an EV, I don't think it's necessary to point out things like different connection types and expected battery life.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer has been a really helpful boost in researching this. I'm finding that the app I use in the US, [PlugShare](//plugshare.com), also has great coverage of the available chargers in Europe. IZIVIA seems like a network with a lot of coverage and I may end up registering there before we leave. Also, and (this is blowing my mind a bit) it appears that many of the [Tesla chargers in France are part of a pilot](https://insideevs.com/news/564345/nontesla-supercharging-pilot-norway-france/) to allow non-Tesla charging at the stations, and offer SAE/combo super-charging!

Comment: That is super interesting! Thanks for mentioning this, I am sure that this could be helpful for others too.